# The Name of "$0$ to $360$ degrees"

Tags: terminology

So in math, there are names for many things:

- Cartesian vs Polar Coordinate systems
- Euclidean vs Non-Euclidean Spaces
- Degrees vs Radians vs [Gradians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradian)

Is there a generally accepted term for `0 to 360` vs `-180 to 180`?

Comment: "*Starting from zero*" versus "*Starting from $-\pi$*?"  Does it really need a name though?  You can describe it in a small number of words easily enough.

Comment: What Principle Argument Range?